# what is the default password of CoreOS?

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtualbox, coreos

i am running CoreOS inside **vagrant** and want to use docker in this way, after i shut down vagrant, i changed the vm name to be shorter one, then i run `vagrant up`, firstly, i found authentication failure problem:

[image: failure pic]

then i press `Ctrl+C` to interrupt it, then i run `vagrant ssh` in the folder, this time, the system ask me for password.

[image: ask for password]

but i have never set such a password, **so what is the default passord for CoreOS? or how can i login to this OS which is running inside vagrant?**

btw, the image of coreos is downloaded from http://beta.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/

some people said the reason system ask for password is the the authentication of public key fails, but why it fails?

`vagrant ssh-keys` shows:

[image: public key]

now i cannot login to coreos even from vbox gui:

[image]

some debug message of `vagrant up`:

[image]

**Edit 1**
seems this problem have something to do with the ssh key, but why the default ssh key failed? and how to solve this problem now?

Comment: There is no default password.  You need to authenticate using an ssh key.

Comment: @larsks why the default ssh key failed?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm not really familiar with vagrant.  I would follow [the docs](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/platforms/vagrant/) as closely as possible. As you can see from the close votes, this question really isn't appropriate to StackOverflow; you may get better answers by asking on a more appropriate site (like [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/), perhaps).

Comment: Setup an http server on the machine you want to have access from. This server should always reply with its own machine's public SSH key. The use `curl` on the CoreOS box to dump the public key into `authorized_keys`. See an example in golang and more details here
https://gist.github.com/francoishill/f2de3021821a4a8f769f

Answer (score 6):

There is no password authentication available for CoreOS, you must use either the default ssh key as specified in the documentation, or equip a cloud config file with a new key.

Quote from the docs: [CoreOS Vagrant Docs](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/platforms/vagrant/)

> You can provide cloud-config data to your CoreOS Vagrant VM by editing the user-data file inside of the cloned directory.

Comment: now coreos is running inside vagrant, , where should i put the file named cloud-config? seems coreos-cloudinit cannot be used on windows:(

Comment: So when you install to disk (like described here https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/installing-to-disk.html), what is the how do you get in? Supposedly, `coreos-install -d /dev/sda -C stable` will produce a usable system, but there's no username/password configured. No ssh keys.